# Login screen renders before skipping

Tags: react-native

After a user logs in to my app, I load a login token using AsyncStorage on every startup on in ComponentWillMount and the screen always renders the screen before skipping to the next screen. Is there a way to create an automatic skip on the login screen after login is completed? I'm using createStackNavigator to navigate my app.

```
 async componentWillMount(){
 let res = await AsyncStorage.getItem("token");

 if (res !== null ){
        this.props.navigation.navigate("nextScreen");
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you have to add some code in your stacknavigation using `createSwitchNavigator`
try creating StackNavigation for login/register screens, call it for example `AuthStack`

```
const AuthStack = createStackNavigator(
   {
      Login: { screen: Login },
      Register: { screen: Register },
   },
   {
      initialRouteName: 'Login',
      headerMode: 'none',
   }
);
```

Then create `AppStack` again just stack with all other screens except login and register

```
const AppStack = createStackNavigator(
   {
      ...
   },
   {
      ...
   }
);
```

Then you will need an `AuthLoadingScreen` this is where you will have your token check code

now all you need to do is create a switch navigator with `createSwitchNavigator` what it does is first call loading screen and check the token then load either app or login screen, it goes like this:

```
const AppNavigator = createSwitchNavigator(
   {
      AuthLoading: AuthLoadingScreen,
      App: AppStack,
      Auth: AuthStack,
   },
   {
      initialRouteName: 'AuthLoading',
   }
);
```

`AuthLoadingScreen`'s code should be something like this, use `componentDidMount` instead of `componentWillMount`

```
componentDidMount = () => {
    const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
    // check if token exist or not 
    if (token) {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('App');
    } else {
      this.props.navigation.navigate('Auth');
    }
}
```

in its render method you may want to add a spinner or just 'Loading...' or whatever you want.

Comment: Awesome, that worked! took me a while since I created the stackNavigators in the incorrect order and now loading feels so smooth. :)